# MP4 H.264 in Flash

Tags: flash, video, mp4

I've noticed FLVs are ubiquitous in flash video, but I'm looking to use MP4s / H.264 in my flash video app.  Has anyone had any problems with using MP4s?  I'm just doing progressive download.

Thanks,
Trevor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works a lot better in most cases. Just make sure your users have a recent version of Flash player 9, or newer. (The first FP9 release did not have h264 support)

Some cons:

- h.264 decoding requires more processing power
- you'll have trouble using the so-called 'pseudo-streaming'

Pros:

- Higher quality/filesize ratio
- You can seek to any frame, rather than just the keyframes with FLV.

I'm sure there's more on both sides, but these are the most obvious.